# Representation exposure

Tags: java

Trying to understand what representation exposure is.
Can you explain the following?

```
public class CharSet2 {
   private ArrayList<Character> elts    = new ArrayList<Character>();

   public void insert(Character c) { elts.add(c); }
   public void delete(Character c) { elts.remove(c); }
   public boolean member(Character c) { return elts.contains(c); }
   public ArrayList<Character> getElts() { return elts; }


   public static void main(String[] args) {
      CharSet2 s = new CharSet2();
      Character a = new Character('X');
      s.insert(a);
      //s.getElts().add(a);
      s.delete(a);
      if (s.member(a)) System.out.println("Has a");
      else System.out.println("No a");
   }
}
```

When s.getElts().add(a) is commented out, the result is "No a", but with it, the result is "Has a". Does this mean that the method insert doesn't do anything to the list elts? I thought both s.insert(a) and s.getElts().add(a) would do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

With the `s.getElts().add(a);` you would have two instances of `a` in the `ArrayList`. So when you remove one, it still has a second.

They do do the same thing, just in different ways.

---

```
s.insert(a);        // Count of a in list -> 1
s.getElts().add(a); // Count of a in list -> 2
s.delete(a);        // Count of a in list -> 1
```

---

The methods in `CharSet2` help encapsulate the `ArrayList`. They don't provide direct access, but can modify control. Although you make no changes between adding it directly and adding it through representation, there is room to change that.

An example of when this would be useful would be if you wanted to add the element at a specific index based off it's hash code. Then, in the `CharSet#insert(Character)` method you can control this behaviour.

Comment: I get it now, but what then is the problem with representation exposure -- ie direct access (through insert) or representative (though getElts)?

Comment: It would be getting the list instance itself. This means that you can circumvent the constraints set in place by the encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are the same. You add `a` two time and [remove](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) it once, so one `a` remains in the list and therefor `s.member` will return true!

If you don't want to expose the internal list then you have to return a read only view of the list or a copy of it.

read only view using [Collections.html#unmodifiableList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29) (an attempt to change the returned list will lead to a `UnsupportedOperationException`)

```
public ArrayList<Character> getElts() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(elts);
}
```

copy:

```
public ArrayList<Character> getElts() { 
    return new ArrayList<(elts);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you you call the add function of List, you are simply adding a reference to the existing object  (Character a = new Character('X');). The add function doesn't create a new, separate instansiation. The following two function calls adds two references in the list to the same instansiated object:
s.insert(a); s.getElts().add(a);

In the following code, I show that even after I set x1 and x2 references to null, there are still three references to the two objects. Also, the first two references in list point to the same object, while the third reference does not.
Output of the following is:
3
true
false

```
    Character x1 = new Character('1');
    Character x2 = new Character('1');

    List<Character> chars = new ArrayList();
    chars.add(x1);
    chars.add(x1);

    chars.add(x2);

    x1=null;
    x2=null;

    System.out.println(chars.size());
    System.out.println(chars.get(0)==chars.get(1));
    System.out.println(chars.get(0)==chars.get(2));
```